# set up user name and password for mongodb with shell script during installation

Tags: mongodb, sh

I use sh script to install mongodb to red hat linux. I want to be able to create username and password for mongodb such as admin/1234 with sh script during installation. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: red hat linux during installation?? I don't understand what you mean, could you please clarify what exactly you mean?

Comment: Are you looking for a procedure like [Enable Client Access](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)? You can script that procedure in the shell script and in a mongo shell script and run the [mongo shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) script from the shell script with mongo <name_of_script>.js